# Table row seen on the second page and first page is empty knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to get rows depending on a particular name, but I am having a problem. The table in the first page shows empty but the data is being loaded in the second page. Here is the examples.
[image]

The first picture is empty and then when I click number 2 the data is there[image]
Here is the code

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: invoicedatasintable">
    <tr data-bind="if : $data.type_txt == 'Repayment invoice' ">
        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.invoiced_total"></span></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.paid_total "></span></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Abbreviation"></span></td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getSelectedInvoice"><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></a></td>

        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.type_txt"></span></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.status_description"></span></td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#" data-bind="if: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total()), click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></a>
            <span data-bind="ifnot: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total())"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></span>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The thing is that I have other invoices too, like Loan invoice and Investment invoice, all coming to the foreach statement but I only want to take this certain Repayment invoice and show it on the table but its weird that it goes to the next page.

Here is the pagination code.

```
 // ****** Processing invoicedatas paging starts here. **********************************************************************

        // Sivutuskäsittelyn vaatima total item count
        self.TotalNumberOfInvoicedatas = ko.observable(0);

        // actual pager, used to bind to the pager's template
        // first parameter must be an observable or function which returns the current 'total item count'.
        // it is wrapped in a ko.computed inside the pager.
        //debugger;
        self.Pagerinvoicedatas = ko.pager(self.TotalNumberOfInvoicedatas);
        self.Pagerinvoicedatas().PageSize(12);

        // Subscribe to current page changes.
        self.Pagerinvoicedatas().CurrentPage.subscribe(function () {
            self.searchInvoicedatas();
        });

        // Subscribe to page size changes.
        self.Pagerinvoicedatas().PageSize.subscribe(function () {
            self.searchInvoicedatas();
        });

        self.searchInvoicedatas = function () {
        // simulate a search

            // ie.:
            var maximumRows = self.Pagerinvoicedatas().PageSize();
            var startIndex = (self.Pagerinvoicedatas().CurrentPage() - 1) * maximumRows;

            self.invoicedatasintable(self.invoicedatas.slice(startIndex, startIndex + (self.Pagerinvoicedatas().PageSize() * 1)));
        };
        // ****** Processing invoicedatas paging ends here. **********************************************************************
```

And the code where I am initialzing the data.

```
self.InitializeInvoiceViewModel = function () {
        var string = 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASEURL + 'index.php/invoice/InvoicesData/' + auth,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: ko.toJSON(string)
        })
        .done(function(invoices) {
            self.invoicedatas.removeAll();
            self.repaymentinvoicedatas.removeAll();
            $.each(invoices, function (index, invoice) {
                self.invoicedatas.push(new InvoiceViewModel(self, invoice));
                self.repaymentinvoicedatas.push(new InvoiceViewModel(self, invoice));
            });
            // holds the total invoicedatas count
            self.TotalNumberOfInvoicedatas(self.invoicedatas().length);
            self.TotalNumberOfRepaymentInvoicedatas(self.repaymentinvoicedatas().length);

            // initialize the invoicedatasintable observable from the invoicedatas observable
            self.searchRepaymentInvoicedatas();
            self.searchInvoicedatas();

            /* If it's requested to display repayment invoice payment confirmation info, display it. */
            if (self.displayModalInfo()) {
                self.showModalPaymentConfirmation();
            }
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status);
        })
        .always(function(data){                 
        });
    };
    self.InitializeInvoiceViewModel();
```

Comment: Please, can you add a sample with mock data on jsfiddle, or here? Perhaps the problem occurs between the logic you use for pagination, and the 'invoicedatasintable' array.

Comment: @jparaya I updated my codes, I couldnt create a jsfiddle since there was alot of information which needs data.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but your problem is the searchInvoicedatas method. Seems its called when PagerIncoicedatas is not completely filled, but I cannot assure without a full sample with a mock of json. Send a console.log with maximumRows, startIndex and specially with self.invoicedatas and check the output. Perhaps your application is executing this before the data arrives, and your pager shows nothing at first. Try moving self.searchInvoicedatas() on .always(function(data))

Comment: @jparaya I tried to do what you said, but now the data loads in the first page properly , but now I have 3 pagination